# List of all my spotify followers using iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, web, spotify

Does anyone know if it's possible to get a list of all my spotify followers' usernames, first/last names and emails using the Spotify iOS SDK or Web API? If so, can someone share how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the iOS SDK you can only access the name, username, follower count and email address of the user that is currently logged in.